# Javascript minification and obfuscation changed numbers in code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify

I ran some code through an online js minified/obfuscator and it changed numbers in the code to some short of shorthand format. For example 30000 became 3e4 and 15000 became 15e3, so e replaces 0 and the following number is the amount of zeros? What exactly has occurred and would it be fine to keep the numbers in this format within my code, for example:

```
 setTimeout(function () {myFunction();}, 3e4);
```

Maybe this is a really stupid question but I'd just like to learn what happened, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just scientific notation.  It's part of the basic syntax of the language.

Numeric literals (that is, numeric constants in your code) can always be expressed with an exponent part, which implicitly indicates a power of 10 by which the first part of the value should be multiplied. The minifier takes advantage of that more compact source notation when possible.

The same sort of notation is common among many programming languages.